# Is it possible to blacklist a NPM package version either in the project or on the machine config?

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

Given the [news that npm 5.7.0](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/02/23/npm_undoes_patch/) had some issues in production, I'm wondering if it's possible to blacklist a package version either in `package.json` or on the machine level perhaps in `.npmrc` or `.yarnrc`.

The behaviour I'm expecting is that upgrades are possible, so this is not a fixed semver version. SemVer has intentionally avoided defining version skipping [in the spec](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/233) because,

> SemVer is meant to communicate what type of changes have occurred, not
>   'how much' change has occurred. If a user wants to know the details of
>   how much has changed, they should look at the changelog. A long
>   changelog tells them it's a big update.

But as a user I may know beforehand that I **never** want **this version**. For example, never use 5.7.0 but 5.7.1 is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have package A that depends on B and B has a known bad version, you can define a version range with a hole in it. See last paragraph of https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver.  I am not aware of any way to globally black-list such a version on your system however, so if you install A and it doesn't have a version hole on its dependency on B, you might have gotten the bad version, but in the example you state above, the offending version was pulled from publication as the news was released regarding the defect.

One thing you can do is purge your cache of any bad package versions to insure that they can't be used to resolve dependencies.